# How to hide autogenerated datetime x axis label in canvas js chart

Tags: jquery, canvas

```
axisX: {
    title: "History",
    valueFormatString: "MM/DD/YY",
    intervalType: "month",
    gridThickness: GridThickness,
    titleFontSize: 8,
    labelFontSize: 8,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `valueFormatString` property to an empty string. [Docs are here](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/)

```
axisX: {
    title: "History",
    valueFormatString: "MM/DD/YY",
    intervalType: "month",
    gridThickness: GridThickness,
    titleFontSize: 8,
    labelFontSize: 8,
    valueFormatString: " ", // x axis label will be empty
},
```

Comment: axisX:{
    gridColor: "Silver",
    tickColor: "silver",
    valueFormatString: " ",
               
  
   },dataPoints: [
                 { x: new Date("5/14/2016 12:00:00 AM"), y: 650,label: "5/14/2016" },
{ x: new Date("5/29/2016 12:00:00 AM"), y: 700,label: "5/29/2016" },
{ x: new Date("5/30/2016 12:00:00 AM"), y: 710,label: "5/16/2016" },
                  
    ] When gap between 2 consecutive dates are high, x labels are not shown

Comment: Is that not what your question is asking for?

Comment: when set valueFormatString="",it got worked.But when the gap between date values are high, xlabel is not shown

Comment: I need to show the x axis labels only for those data points. Some autogenerated start and end date is shown.I need to hide that.